# Unidade monetária com JSON

Tags: json, asp

Estou recebendo do *JSON* um formato de moeda da seguinte maneira

```
"Preco" : "2299.0000"
```

Esta aparecendo no meu formulário (ASP Classic / HTML):

> R$ 22.990.000,00

Como fazer esse tratamento? Tem que usar JS?

O valor correto que deveria aparecer é: *R$ 2299,00*.

Comment: Tens acesso ao código que gera esse JSON? se não acho mesmo que tens de usar JS, mas aí precisamos ver mais exemplos de valores. Pode vir algum valor tipo: `"Preco" : "2299.0000,50"` ou vem sempre assim com 2 casa a mais ?

Comment: Tenho sim. Ele vem do SQL Server, que gera um XML que passa para uma API que me manda em JSON os valores. Terei que fazer essa formatação no SqlServer?

Comment: O ideal é ter o valor certo no JSON, se tem acesso ao código que produz o JSON. O melhor é [edit] a pergunta com essa informação e eventual código relacionado.

Comment: Irei fazer esse tratamento na API que gera o JSON então. Visto que descobri outro problema na data (timestamp) Valeu pelo conselho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Você pode tentar formatar o número assim:

```
FormatNumber(12345.67899)
```

A saída será:

```
12,345.68
```

Mais informações [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_formatnumber.asp).

Comment: Até da certo passando o número direto.
Como eu faria se o valor viesse de um RecordSet?
Ex:
FormatNumber(rsGrid("preco"),2))

Esta vindo errado ainda.

Comment: Escrevendo o rsGrid("preco") direto na página ele vem de que forma?

Comment: Vem 2299.0000 ... Isso que não estava entendo. Eu coloco response.write(rsGrid("preco")) e vem essa forma ai.
Mas quando coloco o formatNumber ele vem 22.990.000,00

Answer (score 1):

Olá agora eu costumo utilizar as duas funções abaixo em JavaScript e funcionam perfeitamente, vou postar abaixo e após deixarei uns exemplos ok.

Em JavaScript:

```
function moedaParaNumero(valor) {
    return isNaN(valor) == false ? parseFloat(valor) : parseFloat(valor.replace("R$", "").replace(".", "").replace(",", "."));

/* Exemplos:
* var a = moedaParaNumero("R$ 10,00"); 
* var b = moedaParaNumero("R$ 100"); 
* var c = moedaParaNumero("0,50"); 
* var d = moedaParaNumero("1.500,00"); 
* var e = moedaParaNumero("89");
* Resultado 10 - 100 - 0.5 - 1500 - 89    
*/
}

function numeroParaMoeda(n, c, d, t) {
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, d = d == undefined ? "," : d, t = t == undefined ? "." : t, s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");

/* Exemplos:
* var a = numeroParaMoeda(10);
* var b = numeroParaMoeda(100);
* var c = numeroParaMoeda(0.5);
* var d = numeroParaMoeda(1500);
* var e = numeroParaMoeda(89);
* Resultado "10,00" - "100,00" - "0,50" - "1.500,00" - "89,00"
*/
}
```

Em ASP Classic

```
<%
'Exemplo 01: FormatCurrency
response.write(FormatCurrency(20000))
'Resposta $20,000.00
'Referência http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_formatcurrency.asp

'Exemplo 02: FormatNumber
response.write(FormatNumber(20000))
'Resposta 20,000.00
'Referência http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_formatnumber.asp
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se continua errado usando o `FormatNumber` é porque talvez vc precisa substituir o ponto por vírgula antes. Dependendo da configuração do `IIS` ele considera o padrão nacional para separação de decimais.

```
resultado = replace(rsGrid("preco"),".",",")
```